# How to use the quick sort to sort by index in a list of a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use a quick sort to sort through a list of lists at index [1].
For example:

```
list = [[2, 5, 3],
        [2, 4, 9],
        [0, 9, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [4, 7, 5]]
```

I want to be able to do this, sorting by index[1]:

```
quickSort(list)

output:

list = [[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 4, 9],
        [2, 5, 3],
        [4, 7, 5],
        [0, 9, 1]]
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `key` argument in `list.sort`:

```
import operator
mylist = [[2, 5, 3],
          [2, 4, 9],
          [0, 9, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [4, 7, 5]]

mylist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Output:

```
>>> mylist = [[2, 5, 3],
...           [2, 4, 9],
...           [0, 9, 1],
...           [1, 1, 1],
...           [4, 7, 5]]
>>> 
>>> mylist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> mylist
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 4, 9], [2, 5, 3], [4, 7, 5], [0, 9, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I need to use the quick sort function. It is for a large project and that is one of the requirements.

Comment: Python's builtin sort is Timsort, which outperforms quicksort on real-world data